# python sensitive to extra parenthesis?

Tags: python, syntax-error, python-2.6, parentheses

This snippet worked fine

```
if True: print "just True"
if (True): print "(True)"
```

Was studying loops and these worked fine

```
for i in range(1, 3):
    print i

i = 0
while i < 3: # without paranthesis
    print i
    i = i + 1

i = 0
while (i < 3): # with paranthesis
    print i
    i = i + 1
```

When I tried

```
for (i in range(1, 3)):
    print i
```

I get an error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

I do understand the outside parenthesis is making for loop go crazy (error) but **which part of the syntax am I violating**? it worked fine in while loop

Comment: One is a loop while the other is a True/False statement?

Comment: `(i < 3)` is an expression, so you can add as many redundant parentheses as you like.  But if you want to add parentheses to a `for` statement, you have to add them to the expression, e.g. `for i in (range(1, 3))`

Comment: @AntonvBR That doesn't have anything to do with it.  The problem is that parentheses were inserted outside of an expression.

Comment: @TomKarzes All I am saying is He/She is comparing apples and oranges

Comment: blame [java for](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) it confused me hehe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

syntax of `for` is (simplified)

```
for <variable(s)> in <expression>
```

[more precisely](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for):

```
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
              ["else" ":" suite]
```

since you're parenthesizing `<variable> in <expression>`, the syntax becomes invalid.

`for` and `in` must be present at the same nesting level.

syntax of `while` is much [simpler](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while):

```
while_stmt ::=  "while" expression ":" suite
                ["else" ":" suite]
```

thus allows parentheses, although not necessary in Python

Answer (score 3):

You can't just lob on extra parenthesis anywhere you want. The `while` syntax, generally stated, is:

```
while <condition>:
```

Here, you're just surrounding a condition with parenthesis, which is fine, as you saw yourself.  The `for` loop's syntax is:

```
for <variable> in <expression>:
```

You could surround the `expression` in parenthesis, but no arbitrary parts of the syntax.